# Idiom for default S4 method?

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

Is there any agreed upon way of writing a fallback method for an S4 generic? I mean, if no signatures are matched, do you write a function to be used as default method that throws perhaps a `message()` explaining valid signatures? And what return value do you use? Or do you throw an error? Or do you do nothing at all and let R throw the usual error `"unable to find an inherited method for function (...)"`.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there’s a agreed-on way, depending on whether a good default function already exists as a non-generic or not.

#### 1. If there’s already a non-generic function that can serve as a default

Simply make it generic:

```
setGeneric('function_name')
```

#### 2. If there’s no non-generic default function yet

1. Define a new generic

   ```
   setGeneric(
       'function_name',
       function (object) {
           standardGeneric('function_name')
       }
   )
   ```
2. Add a default implementation with catch-all parameters

   ```
   setMethod(
       'function_name',
       signature(object = 'ANY'),
       function (object) {
           …
       }
   )
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you can write a generic that might plausibly work for a wide variety of possible classes, then it is common to do so. For example, the (S3) default method for `terms` tries to find a `$terms` component (or attribute — note that this includes the case when the argument is an S4 object with a `@terms` slot) in its first argument:

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    v <- x$terms
    if (is.null(v)) {
        v <- attr(x, "terms")
        if (is.null(v)) 
            stop("no terms component nor attribute")
    }
    v
}
```

(`terms` happens to be an S3 generic but there is no reason why it would not still behave this way if it were S4.)

If there is no sensible thing you can do then all you can really write for a default method is a function that accepts all the arguments in the signature of the generic (plus `...` in case there are some methods that have extra arguments) and just calls `stop` with an error message along the lines of what you suggest.

In S3, you didn't need to do this — you could just not define the default method. This is the case with `predict` — if you call `predict(2,3)` say then you will get an error `no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`. In S4, you will need to define such a default method yourself in the call to `setGeneric`.

Comment: Your answer explains (partially) how to do this for S3. But the process for S4 is quite different.

Comment: Oh, you actually wanted to know how to write such a generic function? I thought you were just after recommended practice. These generics happen to be S3 but there is no reason why they couldn't have been S4 and the argument would still hold.